# Defining a variable and method inside a method Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, jquery-plugins, jquery-localizer

I am using JQuery Localizer plugin. That plugin has a one function defined like that:

```
jQuery.fn.localize = function(stringsVar) {
...
}
```

I want to define a variable inside of it and have an ability to set it. i.e.:
Pseudo code is like that:

```
jQuery.fn.localize = function(stringsVar) {
var defaultLanguage;
defaultlanguage : function(){
   return if defined defaultlanguage else "localizer_en";
}
...
}
```

I run it as like that right now:

```
$('html').localize('localize_tr');
```

So I will able to set default before run it:

```
localizer.defaultlanguage = 'af'; //just a pseudo code
$('html').localize('localize_tr');
```

How can I do that with JQuery/Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially have it already.

```
var defaultLanguage = "af";
jQuery.fn.localize = function(stringsVar) {
alert(defaultLanguage); //"af"
}
```

The problem you might be running into though, is if you define the default language inside another function.  **This won't work:**

```
var FunctionA = function() {
  var defaultLanguage = "af"
}

jQuery.fn.localize = function(stringsVar) {
  alert(defaultLanguage);  // "undefined"
}
```

If this is the case, just make sure you instantiate defaultLanguage outside of Function A.  **This will work:**

```
   var defaultLanguage = "";

   var FunctionA = function() {
      defaultLanguage = "af"
    }

    jQuery.fn.localize = function(stringsVar) {
      alert(defaultLanguage);  // "af"
    }
```

Comment: I want defaultLanguage variable declared inside of localizer. Localizer plugin is a js file and I will call it from my HTML file within script tags. When I want to change that variable I want to write something localizer.defaultLanguage = 'xx' instead of defaultLanguage='xx' so it will be a variable related to that plugin and when I want to change it I wont't confuse what was that variable related to.